# Transport-level error when I try to launch a select from SQL Server to Oracle via Dblink

Tags: sql-server, oracle, dblink

I'm trying to launch a select from Sql Management Studio (SQL Server 2014) on a DBlink that points on an Oracle database that is handled by another company. The results begin to come back to the console and are shown, then, after a while, this error is raised:

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - The pipe has been ended.)

Query example

```
SELECT * from openquery(positions,
 'SELECT * from oracleTableDbLink.POSITION' )
```

It is strange because if I put this simple query on a procedure it works fine.

Comment: The suggestion from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9145977/851930 is to close and reopen SQL Server management studio

Comment: I don't think it is the same problem, I have this problem since 2016

Comment: This really sounds like a timeout issue on the Oracle server force-closing the open connection after a certain period of time - either the query running longer on the Oracle side than the system is configured to leave a port open, or a slowdown on the SQL Server side (or, potentially, across the network) triggering a _'no activity detected for <X time> - assume this port is no longer in use and close the port'_ somewhere along the path between the systems.